# How can I make a prev and next button to show next and prev element of a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a recyclerview. On clicking a item it would display the related field of that item (eg. name, age).

Now i want to make two buttons `prev` and `next` to show the details of previous and next item without going back to the list (in same activity). How can i do that?

Comment: sounds good. go and just do it

Comment: Do you want to show these buttons in each listview Item? And what's your question.

Comment: No,i want to show them on new activity(which is showing details of clicked item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to implement ViewPager. Check [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Here is the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).